# Create Dataset from lists

Tags: dataset, associations

Let's assume I created the following dataset:

```
Dataset[{<|"x" -> a1, "y" -> b1, "z" -> c1|>, <|"x" -> a2, "y" -> b2, 
   "z" -> c2|>, <|"x" -> a3, "y" -> b3, "z" -> c3|>}]
```

[image]

So if I have 3 list of parameters:

```
a = {a1, a2, a3};
b = {b1, b2, b3};
c = {c1, c2, c3};
```

How can I generate automatic Dataset using slots and pure functions without writing each association explicitly.

I have tried somthing like:

```
dataset = 
 Dataset[{<|"x" -> #1, "y" -> #2, "z" -> #3|> & @@ {a, b, c}}]
```

but the output is not what I wanted it to be:

[image]

Any ideas, or other solutions to create dataset from the given lists??

Thanks!

Comment: For such a small set you can do `Dataset[AssociationThread[{"x", "y", "z"} -> #] & /@ 
  Transpose[{a, b, c}]]`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Dataset@MapThread[<|"x" -> #1, "y" -> #2, "z" -> #3|> &, {a, b, c}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This works too:

```
{"x", "y", "z"} -> {a, b, c} // Thread // Map[Thread] // Transpose // 
  Map[Association] // Dataset
```